# The property 'Card_Id' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified. Can anyone tell me why it does happen with EF

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ado.net, sql-server-2012

i have a problem on updating 'Card_Id' primary key using entity framework but the same thing working fine for simple sqlcommand .

my db table is :

create table Bank_Detail(Card_Id  bigint not null primary key, Card_Type nvarchar(60) not null,Cvv bigint not null ,UserName nvarchar(80),Months int not null , Years int not null,BankName_ID int not null foreign key(BankName_ID) references Bank_Name(Id) )

when i am updating information using this code then it is working fine for the upadation of 'Card_Id' which is the primary key on my db

```
          using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
          {
              SqlCommand cmd =
              new SqlCommand("update Bank_Detail Set Cvv=@Cvv , Card_Id =@New_ID ,UserName=@Name,Months=@ExM,Years=@ExY where Card_Id = @Old_ID", con);

              cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Old_ID", Old_ID);
              cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@New_ID", New_ID);
              cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cvv", Cvv);
              cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Name);
              cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ExM", ExM);
              cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ExY", ExY);
              con.Open();
              int val = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
              errormessage.Text = "item Updated successfully";

           }
```

but if i use the entity framework instead of using simple sqlcommand then it throws an exception while upadating 'Card_Id'

it says :"The property 'Card_Id' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified. "

```
 Bank_Detail customerRow = Grid1.SelectedItem as Bank_Detail;

 Bank_Detail bankdetail = bct.Bank_Detail.Single(b => b.Card_Id == Old_ID);
            bankdetail.Card_Id = customerRow.Card_Id;
            bankdetail.Cvv = customerRow.Cvv;
            bankdetail.UserName = customerRow.UserName;
            bankdetail.Months = customerRow.Months;
            bankdetail.Years = customerRow.Years;
            bct.SaveChanges();            
            errormessage.Text = "item Updated successfully";
```

**Note:**
 please do not get confuse with Old_ID .its a global variable for storing my previous Card_Id : 
        public long? Old_ID;

```
  private void SeIndexChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Bank_Detail customerRow = Grid1.SelectedItem as Bank_Detail;
        if (customerRow != null)
        {
            Old_ID = customerRow.Card_Id;
        }

    }
```

**Please Provide the solution If you have any other way to update the same key using Entity Framework**

Comment: Do you want to know why EF does things that way, or do you want a suitable workaround for the limitation to stick in your code?

Comment: Yes . actually i want to achieve the same thing using EF as well and please help me to know why EF  code is showing this exception?